# How to pass form data to ViewModel Properties?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a **.net core 2** code with a simple UI. 
I Want to pass data from my form to action method in my controller which accepts a **ViewModel parameter ( I Have To Use View Model )** But when I submit my form, I get **null** as a result. When I Use **User** as a Parameter type, everything is ok. this is my Code. 

**My Model**

```
 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**My View Model**

```
public class UsersViewModel
    {
        public User NewUser { get; set; }
    }
```

**My Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(UsersViewModel user)
  {
      UserDbContext context = new UserDbContext();
      context.Users.Add(user);
      context.SaveChanges();
      return View();
  }
```

**And My View**

```
@model EFCore2.ViewModels.UsersViewModel


<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="index" method="post">
    <input name="Name" />
    <input name="LastName" />
    <input name="Age" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</form>
```

Help Me Please :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this [doc](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/input-tag-helper):

> The Input tag helper generates appropriate `name` and `id` attribute values based on the **PageModel** property that is assigned to it

In your code, you should add `asp-for` for all of your inputs. and In the passed viewModel, you just have one property with the datatype of `User` and don't have direct access to the `User` properties, so you should access them by calling `NewUser.Name` and... so your view is going to be like below:

```
@model EFCore2.ViewModels.UsersViewModel


<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="index" method="post">
    <input asp-for="NewUser.Name" name="Name" />
    <input asp-for="NewUser.LastName"  name="LastName" />
    <input asp-for="NewUser.Age"  name="Age" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@model EFCore2.ViewModels.UsersViewModel


<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="index" method="post">
    <input asp-for="NewUser.Name"/>
    <input asp-for="NewUser.LastName"/>
    <input asp-for="NewUser.Age"/>
    <br />
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

You don't necessarily have to use the asp-for method but it does make it a little faster in my experience as it can use data annotations to create specific field types like email.

The important thing here is that the **Name Attribute** on the field needs to be **Object.Property** for the object on your viewmodel

The below would also work but you lose out on some of the small benefits asp-for gives you

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="index" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="NewUser.Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="NewUser.LastName"/>
    <input type="number" name="NewUser.Age"/>
    <br />
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```